# Minimizing a univariate function that receives a vector?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to minimise a function of the form

$f(s)=\frac{1}{T}\sum^T_{t=1}(x_t-s_t)^2+\sum^T_{t=2}(s_t-s_{t-1})^2$, where the vector $x$ is fixed, and $T$ is of the order of $10^2$.

I've tried `Minimize[f[s], {s}]`, but Mathematica assumes `s` is just a number and not a vector.

How do I minimize this?

Comment: Might consider using `Indexed[]` to formulate your objective function.

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a mathematics question rather than a Mathematica question, but I will answer with a bit of a Mathematica flavor.

Your function to be minimized can be written as:

$$v = \frac{1}{t} (x-s) \cdot (x-s) + s \cdot M \cdot s$$

where:

$$A = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & -1 \\
 & 1 & -1 \\
 & & \ddots & \ddots \\
 & & & 1 & -1
 \end{array}
 \right)$$

and

$$M = A^T \cdot A$$

The vector derivative with respect to $s$ is:

$$- \frac{2}{t} (x-s) + 2 M \cdot s$$

Setting this to $0$ yields:

$$(I + t M) \cdot s == x$$

where $I$ is the identity matrix. Hence, the minimum occurs at:

$$s = (I + t M)^{-1} \cdot x$$

Here is a function that computes the minimum for $x$:

```
A[dim_] := SparseArray[{Band[{1,1}]->1, Band[{1,2}]->-1}, {dim-1, dim}]
M[dim_] := Transpose[A[dim]] . A[dim]

mins[x_] := With[{dim = Length[x]},
    LinearSolve[IdentityMatrix[dim, SparseArray] + dim M[dim], x]
]
```

Example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
x = RandomReal[1, 5]
s = mins[x]

1/5 (x - s) . (x - s) + s . M[5] . s
```

> {0.817389, 0.11142, 0.789526, 0.187803, 0.241361}
>
> {0.506737, 0.444606, 0.449113, 0.385537, 0.361507}
>
> 0.0838865

Let's check this using [`ArgMin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArgMin):

```
s = Array[t, 5];
ArgMin[1/5 (x - s) . (x - s) + s . M[5] . s, s]
```

> {0.506737, 0.444606, 0.449113, 0.385537, 0.361507}

Larger example:

```
SeedRandom[2]
x = RandomReal[1, 100];
s = mins[x]; //AbsoluteTiming

1/100 (x - s) . (x - s) + s . M[100] . s
```

> {0.000458, Null}
>
> 0.0693302

Comment: As an addendum to Carl's fabulous answer: the matrix $\mathbf M$ is a specially-structured tridiagonal matrix with [known eigenstructure](http://www.math.nthu.edu.tw/~amen/2005/040903-7.pdf), which should allow for closed-form solutions for the components of the solution vector.

Comment: Carl, thanks for your answer. I do think my question was more on the Mathematica than mathematics side, while your answer was more on the mathematics side.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference ( I used J.M. helpful comment).

```
HPo[lambda_, x_] := 
      1/T *Sum[(data[[i]] - Indexed[x, i])^2, {i, 1, T}] + 
       lambda/T*
        Sum[((Indexed[x, i + 1] - Indexed[x, i]) - (Indexed[x, i] - 
              Indexed[x, i - 1]))^2, {i, 2, T - 1}];
    hpdata = ArgMin[HPo[16, x], Table[Indexed[x, i], {i, 1, T}]];
```

Comment: I know this is very inefficient, but it works for my purpose.

Comment: You don't need the `Table[]` in `ArgMin[]`; `ArgMin[HPo[16, x], x]` should already work.

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less I tried it, and It doesn't...